# Accessing ActiveRecord Results Causes UndefinedMethod Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Migrating a site from Rails 2.2.2 to Rails 3

I am running a query and storing it in variable @user but when I try to access the members of @user I get an error even though @user was hydrated and has a value for "is_admin"

```
### @user.inspect returns
[#<B2bUser id: 398, name: "Tim Test", email: "tim_test@test.com", username: "timtest", password: "foo", is_admin: true, company: "Test Co.", sent_welcome_email: true, created_at: "2011-12-14 08:32:31", send_email_reminders: false, api_username: "api.tim_test@test.com", api_password: "FOOBAR", login_attempts: nil, last_login_attempt_at: nil>]
```

**But when I call this from it's view:**

```
<% if (@user.is_admin) %>
```

**I get this:**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `is_admin' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xaa5db4c>):
    14:
    15:         <%= render :partial => "/warning" %>
    16:
    17:         <% if (@user.is_admin) %>
    18:
    19:                
    20:
```

In the same view the same type of error (undefined method p.vendor_name) occurs when more than 1 row is returned such as:

```
<% for p in @privileges %>

        <% next if !p.can_setup_purchase_orders and !p.can_setup_instant_electronic_delivery %>

        <h2>For <%= p.vendor_name %></h2>
```

Here is my controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

 before_filter :authenticate

  def index
    @nav = []
    @user = B2bUser.where(:id => request.session[:user_id])
    #logger.debug @user.inspect
    @privileges = B2bPrivilege.lookup_all request.session[:user_id]
    #logger.debug @privileges.inspect

    @can_asn = false
    @can_push_xml = false

    for p in @privileges
      if p.can_setup_advance_ship_notification?
            @can_asn = true and break
        end
         if p.can_setup_xml_pushes?
                @can_push_xml = true and break
            end


    end

  end

end
```

Here is my method lookup_all
class B2bPrivilege < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  def B2bPrivilege.lookup_all current_user_id

    #return B2bPrivilege.find(:all, :conditions => "b2b_user_id = #{current_user_id}", :joins => "LEFT JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = b2b_privileges.vendor_id", :select => "b2b_privileges.*, vendors.name AS vendor_name")
    return B2bPrivilege.joins('LEFT JOIN  vendors ON vendors.id = b2b_privileges.vendor_id').where('b2b_user_id' => current_user_id)
    #return B2bPrivilege.find_by_sql["SELECT b2b_privileges.*, vendors.name AS vendor_name FROM b2b_privileges LEFT JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = b2b_privileges.vendor_id WHERE b2b_user_id = ?", current_user_id]
end
```

Do I need to access the members in @user differently? This used to work in Rails 2.2.2/Ruby 1.8.7

Thanks

Comment: did you try @user.is_admin?

Comment: Yes - Same result: undefined method `is_admin?' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xafc1d54>

Comment: what does your controller look like?

Comment: Updated my question such that it now includes the controller and the lookup_all method used by the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely you'll see that `@user` is actually a ActiveRecord::Relation object, not a User. If you're only ever going to have one user in that list then you get to the field you want with `@user.first.is_admin`.

However, it would make more sense to set `@user` to be the first result in the controller.

**UPDATE:** *where* in rails returns a Relation, which is an array like object. It does not return a single model record. Use `B2bUser.find(request.session[:user_id])` instead to get a single User record.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I added more details to my question. Thanks

Comment: Yes, thanks. @user.first.is_admin does return a value however your .find example give me: Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Strange, ActiveRecord's `find` expects an ID: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class. Oh well, glad you got it working.